# Algorithm to Resolve Conflicts on a Timeline Based on Priority Value

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to come up with an algorithm to re-organize an array of ***Event*(StartTime,EndTime)**'s where any overlaps are resolved (flattened) according to a priority value. There are **at most 2 events** in an overlap as in the picture. Imagine that I have the following timeline, which each event has an associated value:

[image]

I need to find and consider conflicts as follows:

1. A vs. B: take B for conflict area:
   *Add to Final List:* `A [0:00, 0:15]` (modified A)
   *Add to Final List:* `B [0:15, 0:30]`
2. A vs. C: take A for conflict area:
   *Need to create a new Event, Add to Final List:* `A-NEW1 [0:30, 1:15]` *Note that C goes away completely*
3. A vs. D: take A for conflict area:
   *Keep `A-NEW1` unchanged*
   *Add to Final List:* `D [1:15, 2:00]` (modified D)
4. D vs. E: take E for conflict area:
   *Add to Final List:* `D [1:15, 1:45]` (modified D)
   *Add to Final List:* `E [1:45, 2:30]`

**Final List:**

```
A      [0:00, 0:15]
B      [0:15, 0:30]
A-NEW1 [0:30, 1:15]
D      [1:15, 1:45]
E      [1:45, 2:30]
```

My main question is, how do I loop in this algorithm? I can't just consider each **N and N+1** in a straight for-loop. For example, I don't want to compare **B/C** because they don't overlap. It seems that I have to consider each **conflicting pair in a conflict group**. But I'm not clear on how to find these conflict pairs in a group, and how to loop over them. Is that a Cartesian product or something?

Also, in general terms, it looks like

```
   (when all events are Sorted ASC by StartTime)

   1. Comparing N and N+1: if N has priority:
      1a. If N+1 fully contained within (N+1's EndTime <= N's EndTime):
          Add N
          Do not add N+1
      1b. If N+1 not fully contained within (N+1's EndTime > N's EndTime):
          Add N
          Add N+1(N's EndTime, N+1's EndTime)
   2. Comparing N and N+1: if N+1 has priority:
      Add N(StartTime, N+1's StartTime)
      Add N+1
```

But this logic does not take into account the creation of "**New**" events that are sometimes necessary, as shown in the **A/C** comparison above. We need to sometimes create a "continuation" event and the original event may get broken up.

Any thoughts on this problem, and how to loop properly?

Answer (score 1):

A naive method could be to split all events in elementary 15 (or 5, or 1) minute intervals, then resolve conflicts on each slice, and finally coalesce adjacent slices pointing to the same event.

In this case:

```
12:00 find event A, A = [12:00-12:01]
12:01 find event A, A = [12:00-12:02]
...
12:15 find events A and B, B wins: B [12:15-12:16]
12:16 find events A and B, B wins: B [12:15-12:17]
12:30 find events A and C, A wins: A1 [12:30-12:31]
...
13:00 find events A and D, A wins: A1 [12:30-13:01]
...
13:14 find events A and D, A wins: A1 [12:30-13:15]
13:15 find event D: D [13:15-13:16]
...
```

When the "winning" event is the same as the "active" event, you prolong the active event. When it is not, you add a new event; if the event has a label ("A") that has been already used, you increment its counter.

So you need to keep a queue of "winning" events, and a list of "known" events with their counter.

Comment: That's great. In my case the smallest unit is 5 min. thanks

Comment: The question of how to implement your `find()` method is also interesting, it should probably a binarySearch rather than a full-scan search, because it doesn't make sense to scan all existing events for a given time frame if my events are already pre-sorted by StartTime.

Comment: @geneb. yes, absolutely. Once you have a sorted heap, you can resume the search from the last event and stop as soon as you "exit" the current event's timeframe. Also, if you have only one event from 12:00 to 15:00, it makes no sense to test all 5-minutes in the middle, you can jump directly to 15:00. The algorithm I presented is very naive and optimizable.